# Close insert query inside a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to loop a insert query, however i keep getting an error, which seem to be related to my close() statements?

i have following code which keep returning following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in
```

i've on purpose removed the information $variables in the insert_news query, inorder to simplify the question

```
function check_text($text, $last_id) {
    global $ids;
    foreach($ids as $id => $teams) {
        foreach($teams as $team) {
            if(stripos(($text, $team) !== false) {

            $teamRelation = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO contain (`team_id`, `news_id`) VALUES (?, ?)");
            $teamRelation->bind_param("ii", $id, $last_id);
            $teamRelation->execute();

            }
         }
    }

    $teamRelation->close();

}

function scrape_afton() {

foreach($afton->find("//section/ul/li") as $afton_element) {

            $insert_news = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO news (`title`, `url`, `image_url`, `date`, `news_text`, `website_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1)");
            $insert_news->bind_param("sssss", $afton_title, $afton_link, $afton_img, $afton_datetime, $full_text_dont);
            $insert_news->execute();
            $afton_last_id = $con->insert_id;

            check_text($afton_full_text, $afton_last_id);

}
}
```

Comment: Try `$con->close()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722159/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-close-on-a-non-object-mysqli-issue

Comment: I think you need to close connection there. try what @Maximus2012 said

Comment: close connection where?

Comment: Try `$con-close();` in place of `$teamRelation->close();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$con is not defined within the function. I'm assuming it's a global, so add it to your globals:

global $ids,$con;